# Apache DerbyDB log, how to read transaction log

Tags: derby

In case you think this may be related to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744985/how-to-read-apache-derby-database-log), I think the answer is possibly, but I'm not sure.

I'm looking for a utility where I can easily read the transaction logs that occur in a DerbyDB (embeded, although it may end up in a server later!).

I'm not hugely interested in the the system logs as a whole, simply the updates to fields in the database. My application grabs the name of the current user on the system and uses this to log into the embeded DB.

I'm sure the derby logs the info of the user and the field name, table name (and some sort of 'key' reference) for the row in the database, and the new value that has been input into the field. If it includes the old value great, although I'm sure a 'search' would enable a view of what the old and updated values were / are would be reasonably easy.

I'v looked at the info for the [derby DB log format](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/logformats.html), but it is fairly technical, and I don't immediately see a reference into the values I'm interested in.

If the solution suggested in the first link will also provide a solution for me, that is great. Or does derby store this info in a system table somewhere, for more easy access, if so I haven't yet found this info.

A good alternative would be the ability to use log4j to view the files, if at all possible.

Your thoughts and answers are much appreciated.

thanks in advance.

David

Answer (score 0):

Check out these tools: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-5195

They sound like what you're interested in.

Comment: I will have a look at these, but I fear that the derby logs don't specifically log user names, unless they log this in some 'coded' forme, that I'm not immediately seeing.