# How to read an error message 'database not found' from apache derby?

Tags: java, derby

I usually program in other languages but that's nearly my first exposure to Java; I have been asked to understand the following error log, coming from an program that makes use of apache derby.

I see that the trouble is in the line

```
java.sql.SQLException: Database '/infermeria' not found.
```

but after reading

- https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/getstart/cgstutorialintro.html
- [How to read Apache Derby database log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744985/how-to-read-apache-derby-database-log)
- [Database not found error in Apache Derby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653905/database-not-found-error-in-apache-derby)

I can't still tell if I'm facing a mere path problem or a deeper bug.

So I have tried the most childish trick of all, copying infermeria.jar in every directorybut it still doesn't work.

Therefore the question arise: does such a log suffices to detect the problem ?

Thanks for your replies !!

```
23/02/2015 11:04:44 [INFO ] Infermeria launched.
23/02/2015 11:04:45 [DEBUG] Trying to connect to: jdbc:derby:/infermeria
23/02/2015 11:04:45 [ERROR] Exception preparing statements
java.sql.SQLException: Database '/infermeria' not found.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleDBNotFound(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at infermeria.Application.prepareStatements(Application.java:136)
    at infermeria.Application.<init>(Application.java:88)
    at infermeria.Application$1.run(Application.java:1710)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Database '/infermeria' not found.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 31 more
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653905/database-not-found-error-in-apache-derby) issue.

Try specifying the full path to your database: "jdbc:derby:/path/to/my/db/infermeria".